# What does `it.` do when used in Entity's OrderBy method?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

In one of the tutorials on Entity/WebAPI that I'm following, I saw the following line of code:

```
var list = ((IObjectContextAdapter) db).ObjectContext.CreateObjectSet<Item>();
list.OrderBy(String.Format("it.{0} {1}", sort, desc ? "DESC" : "ASC"));
```

There is something that I have been trying to figure out but to no avail, and that is for what is the `it.` prepended in the `String.Format` in the second line? It seems arbitrary to me at first. I tried removing the `it.` from the string and I get a 500 internal error.

What does that `.it` part in the OrderBy string format do? Why do I need that? It doesn't make a lot of sense to me, but why can't I leave it out without errors?

Comment: That's the parameter name.

Comment: Let's say `sort = Name`. Then it will be `it.Name DESC`. I don't remember having a variable `it` in any where of my code. I tried to do a search and I can't find.

Comment: It's the implicit parameter name in the dynamic LINQ query expression.

Comment: Oh.. what does it actually mean to have that parameter name? What is it for? Is there a documentation on this?